# What is a green cue point in Traktor?

Tags: traktor

I accidentally hit something on my controller that produced an unusual-looking cue point in Traktor—a green, rectangular flag:

[image]

To the left is a normal cue point, for comparison. To the right is a normal loop.

What is the green cue point, and how can I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZqsEHbCi4s) that these green cue points are actually **saved loops**.

Just as you can save a cue point at your current position by selecting an empty cue slot, you can also save your current loop (*i.e.* the green region created with either fixed-length loop options or custom loop IN / OUT functions) by selecting an empty cue slot while the loops is active.

To get rid of it, simply delete the cue point as you would any other cue point.